# Using LockBits generates weird image

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, gdi+, lockbits

I'm trying to write out a grayscale image using Lockbits, my current code looks is

```
/// <summary>
/// Save the content of the FrameProc out to a bitmap
/// </summary>
public void Save(string path)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.size.Width, this.size.Height
                           ,PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    var data = bmp.LockBits(this.size, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    unsafe
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < this.size.Height; y++)
        {
            byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride);
            for (int x = 0; x < this.size.Width; x++)
            {
                byte value = (byte)this.buffer[y, x];
                row[x*Bits+r] = value; 
                row[x*Bits+g] = value;
                row[x*Bits+b] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

where

```
/// <summary>
/// The amount of Bytes per pixel in the image
/// </summary>
private const int Bits = 4;

/// <summary>
/// Image components
/// </summary>
private const int a=3, r = 2, g = 1, b = 0;
```

However the image i receive is not correct:

[image: Broken image]

Maybe this is related to how i'm reading them in? So here's that code

```
    public FrameProc(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        this.size=new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), bmp.Size);
        var data = bmp.LockBits(this.size
                               ,ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                               ,bmp.PixelFormat);
        this.buffer = new Matrix(this.size.Height, this.size.Width);

        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.size.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride);
                for (int x = 0; x < this.size.Width; x++)
                {
                    this.buffer[y,x] = 0.299*row[x*Bytes+r] 
                                     + 0.587*row[x*Bytes+g] 
                                     + 0.114*row[x*Bytes+b];
                }
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure your choice of image will be to everyone's taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the results you're getting - it looks *exactly* as if each pixel is three bytes big and not four as you have declared it - and as one would expect. (Note: you called it Bits - but that's wrong - it should be namned Bytes, not Bits).

I'd experiment with any one of this:

- change from 4 to 3 bytes
- change from Format32bppRgb to Format32bppArgb and fill out the alpha with 255
- change from 4 to 3 bytes and from Format32bppRgb to from Format24bppRgb

I would also rewrite the loop slightly for performance (sorry, I can't help myself):

```
for (int x = 0; x < this.size.Width; x++, row += Bits) 
                { 
                    byte value = (byte)this.buffer[y, x]; 
                    row[r] = value;  
                    row[g] = value; 
                    row[b] = value; 
                }
```

But were you really would get more speed if you get a pointer to this.buffer using the fixed keyword. Yes, you're not having any performance problems, but I couldn't help myself from mentioning it!

Comment: That loop would skyp 3 bytes at a time, the image would end up with holes. Row is 3 times larger than this.buffer, since buffer only holds only Y and row the RGBx values.

Comment: Yes exactly - you increment row INSTEAD of doing the unnecessary  x*Bits multiplication on each round. Believe me, I do image processing and .LockBita *a lot*. But i never ever used the Format32bppRgb  format.

Comment: Hm, Not sure what's going on with the Format32bppRgb, but Format24bppRgb seems to be working. If you have any idea why Format32bppRgb didn't work I would love to hear it though. I assumed the last 8 bytes were ignored/padding.

Comment: So was I, from the documentation. But I immediately recognized the effect you were experiencing. I've seen it when I accidentally stepped 4 bytes/pixel on a Format24bppRgb image. It is a shame really that there is no way to ask the framework how many bytes/pixel a certain format is using!

Comment: Yeah, that would be handy/useful to know.

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to add this comment for people who find this question through Google (like me): You could try dividing PixelFormat.BitsPerPixel by 8 to get the desired result. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformat.bitsperpixel.aspx

Comment: @DanByström could you please show in the code where to use ´fixed´ to make it faster? thanks!

Comment: @Vlad L You would surrond the code with a "fixed ( byte* pbuffer = this.buffer )" and then you would use pbuffer instead of this.buffer in the loop. Note that you cannot do the double indexing [x,y] then, but have to figure out how to do it in another way... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function indeed:

```
public Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Bitmap original)
{
   unsafe
   {
      //create an empty bitmap the same size as original
      Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

      //lock the original bitmap in memory
      BitmapData originalData = original.LockBits(
         new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
         ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

      //lock the new bitmap in memory
      BitmapData newData = newBitmap.LockBits(
         new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height), 
         ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

      //set the number of bytes per pixel
      // here is set to 3 because I use an Image with 24bpp
      int pixelSize = 3;

      for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
      {
         //get the data from the original image
         byte* oRow = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);

         //get the data from the new image
         byte* nRow = (byte*)newData.Scan0 + (y * newData.Stride);

         for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
         {
            //create the grayscale version
            byte grayScale = 
               (byte)((oRow[x * pixelSize] * .11) + //B
               (oRow[x * pixelSize + 1] * .59) +  //G
               (oRow[x * pixelSize + 2] * .3)); //R

            //set the new image's pixel to the grayscale version
            nRow[x * pixelSize] = grayScale; //B
            nRow[x * pixelSize + 1] = grayScale; //G
            nRow[x * pixelSize + 2] = grayScale; //R
         }
      }

      //unlock the bitmaps
      newBitmap.UnlockBits(newData);
      original.UnlockBits(originalData);

      return newBitmap;
   }
}
```

Source and other interesting examples (with theory behind) could be taken from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale)

Comment: The actual operation I'm trying to do isn't just converting the image to grayscale. I'm doing image processing on the byteof the image where converting to grayscale is just the first step. So I do need to do operations that can't be covered by a ColorMatrix.

Comment: @Phyx: on link I posted in my answer you find a function _MakeGrayScale_ using `LockBits`: take a look at that.

Comment: @Phyx: I've just edited my answer writing the function found in that link

Comment: I don't actually see a difference between that code and mine, except I temporarily store the pixels somewhere and this code directly converts to grayscale